# Qualitative prediction based off data containing mixed qualitative and quantitative values?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, sql

I'm trying to find a way to predict an integer value based off of an item's prior sale history and am inquiring for a starting point on how to approach this.

The factors are as follows (Data Type in Parenthesis):

**A)** ReportDate (DateTime)

**B)** Part# (String)

**C)** Part Type  (String)

**D)** Lost Sales in past 150 days (Int)

**E)** Sales in past 150 days  (Int)

**F)** Quantity currently in stock (Int)

**G)** Quantity to be Purchased  (Int)

My goal is to minimize **Factor D** so that it closes in at 0 as **Factor G** has better inputs. It should also account for what is already in stock aka **Factor F**

**Factor G** is manually inputted data while the other data is automatically generated. **Factor G's** value is based on the item's sale history.

There is a monthly reporting of each item spanning over the past 5 years.

For now, I am just concerned with being able to predict one item correctly.

So if I had 5 years of data from 2013-2018, that would be 60 rows of data.

It is now January 2019, so I should expect a row of data with **Factor G** missing, this is where I would need to predict a value.

---

Also, is it possible to account for report dates since Lost 150 and Sales in past 150 are dependent on the past 5 rows?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is very broad...